# How to disable writing to database if i made duplicate entry, and show warning in alertbox?

Tags: php, javascript

I am a bit new with php, so I need help. On one page i have small form with firstname and lastname fields. On submit i send it to external .php script where i want to check if there is already person with same name in database. If there is already person with entered name in database, I want to cancel writing to database, and return to the html page. I have done this, but I want to display the JS messagebox "Person with this name already exists in db!", and if the writing to base was canceled, i want my input fields show last written values. I've been reading a lot of litertaure, and I'm lost. Thanks for help anyway :)

This is my form:

```
<form name="form" action="write.php" method="post" onSubmit="return Validate()">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

My php code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phptest");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) { 
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
}
if (isset($_POST['lastname'])) { 
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
}
$duplicate=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons WHERE FirstName='$firstname'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($duplicate)>0)
{
die('Name already exists' );//I want that this message shows in html file, as alert
}
else{
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES('$firstname','$lastname')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!$result)
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}
}
header( 'Location://localhost/ivanda.php' ) ;
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($duplicate)>0)
{
die('Name already exists' );//I want that this message shows in html file, as alert
}
```

Change it to this this code:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($duplicate)>0)
{
echo "<script>alert('Name already exist!!!'); </script>";
echo "<script>window.location.assign('ivanda.php'); </script>"; //add this line instead of header


}
```

-------------------------EDITED----------------------------------

Trys this:

```
    $duplicate=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE FirstName='$firstname' limit 1");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($duplicate)>0)
    {

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($duplicate);

    echo "<script>alert('Name already exist!!!'); </script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.assign('ivanda.php?firsName=".$row['FirstName']."&lastName=".$row['LastName']."'); </script>"; //add this line instead of header

    }
    else{
    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES('$firstname','$lastname')";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if (!$result)
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    }
```

With this you are sending the var via GET on the url...then in your form you should have something like this:

```
<form name="form" action="write.php" method="post" onSubmit="return Validate()">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['firsName'])){echo $_GET['firsName'];} ?>">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['lastName'])) {echo $_GET['lastName'];} ?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

PS: Go for mysqli o PDO, remember it...mysql extension is gonna be deprecated soon

Saludos.

Comment: i've already tried this, it works, but I cant' redirect myself then to html page ://

Comment: and if i redirect with: header( 'Location://localhost/ivanda.php' ) ; then i can't read this message, same thing for JS method history.back()

Comment: this helped, i get what I needed, but partially, when i get redirected back to my form, my last inputed values aren't there. I'm working on project which has 20 input fields, so if my input was invalid, I want to show message(you demonstrated this), and get me back to the form, but with all last inputed values still in their input fields. With that i wouldn't have to type again 20 input fields from the beggining... this helped me, but didn't solved this problem :/